# Python 3, Beautifulsoup, and urlopen web scraping

Tags: python-3.x, web, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, urlopen

I am scraping this [website](https://www.olx.com.ng/)  website for information about products such as product description and price. the website is using pagination  to load just the first 20 products  and when i do the scraping my program just gets the first 20 products. How can i get all this products.
here is my code

```
 from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
 from urllib.request import urlopen
 import csv
 import random


myfile = open('example.csv', 'w')

def scrape():
    page = urlopen('https://www.olx.com.ng/')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read(), 'html.parser')


    for price, description  in zip(soup.findAll('p', 
    {'class':'_13OzP'}),soup.findAll('p',{'class':'_2uySz'})):
    info = price.text + ' -------------------------- ' + description .text
    print(info)
```

`
This is a sample image of the html structure [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pdGYU.png)  check the areas i have mark with red on the image

Comment: You can't with just beautifulsoup, consider using selenium to automate the clicking of next button, or be real hacky to simulate the API request to get the result of next page.

Comment: For this you need to use selenium to navigate to page and use seleniums ability to load javascript to scroll down in order to upload all the data. I would suggest first load all data, then scrape it.

Comment: Ok thanks please can i get any good tutorial on selenium ?

Comment: Even when i manage to manually load more pages it still did not get all the data it still return just the first 20

Comment: I use selenium sometimes but often there are much better ways, in this case use the API.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the API directly. You need to read the "cursor" from the first request and pass it to the next request to get the next set of results. This example uses requests but you can adapt it to use urllib easily.

```
import requests
import json
cursor = "0"
for i in range (30):
    r = requests.get("https://www.olx.com.ng/api/items?query=%7B%22sorting%22%3A%22desc-creation%22%7D&cursor=" + cursor)
    j = r.json()
    cursor = j['metadata']['cursor']
    for d in j['data']:
        print ("Title: {}, Price {}".format(d['title'].encode("utf-8"), d['price']['value']['raw']))
```

Outputs:

```
Title: Brand New 2.5HP Electric Motorized Treadmill With Mp3 Player Exercise, Price 250000
Title: Tokunbo Toyota Venza 2012 White, Price 6500000
Title: Clean Registered 2007 Toyota Tundra, Price 3550000
Title: Ladies Bike Hajour Lucky, Price 80000
Title: 110k p/a two bedroom to let in Agbede, Price 110000
...
```